# Is it a good idea to pause DB replication as a way to resolve consistency issues?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

When running a distributed operation over a set of nodes, is it a good idea to pause replication to a db replica (where input data to the operation is read) to ensure that all nodes see the same consistent view of the input data, and resume replication when all nodes finish the computation?

Answer (score 0):

Almost any group communication toolkit (e.g., [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/)) will take care of this on your behalf, you don't need to be concerned about this. Also, if all nodes see the same consistent view of the data, it means the data is also replicated.